# How can I evaluate the following Lebesgue measures?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, statistics, lebesgue-measure

We have two functions:

$$
f(x)=1-|x|, \quad -1\leq x \leq 1, \qquad g(x)=|x|, \quad -1 \leq x \leq 1.
$$

We also know that

$$
f^{*}(x)=\sup\{c:\,m(c)>x\}, \quad x>0
$$

and that

$$
m(c)=\mu\{t:\,f(t)>c\}
$$

where $\mu$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

We have to find $m_{f}(c)$ and $m_{g}(c)$, using the definition of $m(c)$.

RESULT: $m_{f}(c)=m_{g}(c)=\mu\{x:\,g(x)>c\}=2(1-c)I_{[0, 1]}(c),$ where $I$ is the indicator function.

We also have to find $f^{*}(x)$ ad $g^{*}(x)$, using the definition told before.

RESULT: $f^{*}(x)=g^{*}(x)=\left(1-x/2\right)I_{[0, 2)}(c)$.

Which are the steps that lead to the two results?

Comment: You will get more attention and more helpful answers if you edit your question to describe your work or thoughts so far, even if you think it's wrong, or if you only have ideas without concrete steps.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=[-1,1]$. The Lebesgue measure $\mu$ is an additive set function, and

$\{x \in X: |x| > c\}=\{x \in X: 1 \geq x > c\} \cup\{x \in X: -c > x \geq -1\}$,

$0 \leq c \leq 1$. Denoting the first set on the right by $A(c)$, the latter by $B(c)$,

$\mu(A(c) \cup B(c))=\mu(A(c)) + \mu(B(c))=1-c+1-c=2(1-c), \quad 0 \leq c \leq 1.$

Similarly,

$\{x \in X: 1-|x| > c\}=\{x \in X: -(1-c) < x \leq 0\} \cup \{x \in X:1-c > x \geq 0\}$,

$0 \leq c \leq 1$. Evaluate and conclude on the first part.

As for the second part, note that $\mu(A(c))=\mu(B(c))$, with $A(c)$ and $B(c)$ as above. As such, and by a simple illustration on a piece of paper,

$2\mu(A(c))>x \Longleftrightarrow \mu(A(c)) > x/2 \Longleftrightarrow 1-x/2 > c, \ x > 0, \ 0 \leq c \leq 1$.

The remaining case follows similarly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Using the same approach, I have now to evaluate the $f^{*}(x)$ knowing that $f$ is the pdf of a variable $X$ having normal distribution with parameters $\mu=0$ and $\sigma^2=1$. How can I do that?